# Safari on Mac displays caret symbol in my form

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, safari

I have a form with several fields (many of which are datepicker fields) and only three of them show these weird artifacts

[image]

Here are the same fields in Chrome, but it appears the same on every other browser... including Safari on Windows (on a different computer, not a VM or parallels)

[image]

Here is the relevant code:

```
<legend>Delivery Information</legend>


<div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :start_date,
      "Start Date <span class='red-text'>*</span>".html_safe,
      class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.text_field :start_date, class: "form-control datepicker",
        required: false,
        value: (model.start_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") rescue "") %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :end_date,
      "End Date <span class='red-text'>*</span>".html_safe,
      class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.text_field :end_date, class: "form-control datepicker",
        required: false,
        value: (model.end_date.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") rescue "") %>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :last_day_of_classes,
        "Last Day of Classes <span class='red-text'>*</span>".html_safe,
        class: "col-sm-4 control-label" %>
    <div class="col-sm-5">
      <%= f.text_field :last_day_of_classes, class: "form-control datepicker",
        required: false,
        value: (model.last_day_of_classes.strftime("%m/%d/%Y") rescue "") %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

`model` is just because this is a shared form.

I have no idea why these fields are displaying this way... any ideas?

Comment: That's a [Caret](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret), not a [Carrot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrot). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So. By changing the class name from `datepicker` to `pickerDates` on those three fields the carets have disappeared. I don't know why or how.